# Can't reach docker network in a VM with bridged network

Tags: docker, docker-compose, virtualbox, docker-network

I have two docker container running on default network on my Ubuntu PC. And I have an Ubuntu VM running on the same PC with a bridged adapter(wlp3s0) and I am trying to run 2 more containers on the default docker network of the PC.

docker_compose.yml file in the PC:

```
test/docker_compose.yml

version: "3.4"
services:
  container_1:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    expose:
      - "5000"

  container_2:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./2/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5001:5001"
    expose:
      - "5001"

networks:
  default:
    driver: bridge
```

docker_compose.yml file in VM:

```
test/docker_compose.yml

version: "3.4"
services:
  container_1:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    expose:
      - "5000"

  container_2:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./2/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5001:5001"
    expose:
      - "5001"

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: test_default
```

`docker network list` produces below result in PC:

```
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
e3c3a779e67a        bridge              bridge              local
6ffc94e5474c        host                host                local
3a177ebcdaae        none                null                local
40ea39edee9a        test_default        bridge              local
```

`docker network list` produces below result in VM:

```
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
e3c3a779e67a        bridge              bridge              local
6ffc94e5474c        host                host                local
3a177ebcdaae        none                null                local
```

As seen above, I can not connect to test_default network in VM. Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: The Docker networks are private to the system they're running; they don't cross VM or other host boundaries.

Comment: @DavidMaze So there is no way to make these containers communicate with each other in an easy way?

Comment: You need to use the host's/VM's IP address, and the published `ports:` number, the same way as if the containers were running on two physically separate hosts.

Comment: @DavidMaze Use in where exactly? They are running in the same network and as far as I know, they should detect each other. Is this correct? Do I need to do anything extra?

Comment: They're not on the same network, because they're not using the same Docker daemon on the same host.  One network only exists in the VM and the other only exists outside of it.